# PIVOT other items in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that I need to PIVOT its columns but I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do it.

Here's the portion of my table:

```
Category | Item | Total
Food     |  1   | $500
Food     |  2   | $1,000
Food     |  3   | $750
```

Pivot result (which is correct):

```
Category | item_1  | item_2  | item_3
 Food    |  $500   | $1,000  | $750
```

my code:

```
SELECT category,
       [1] as item_1,
       [2] as item_2,
       [3] as item_3
FROM (
SELECT category, item, SUM(item_total) as item_total FROM (
     SELECT category, item, total
     FROM tbl_product
     where category = 'Food'
     ) prod
GROUP BY category, item) sourcetable
PIVOT
(
AVG(item_total)
FOR item IN ([1],[2],[3])
) as PivotTable;
```

However, I do have more than 50 items. I would like to group these items into columns.

Example: items 7-20 should be in misc_1 column, 21-50 as misc_2 column
so it would look like this:

```
Category | item_1  | item_2  | item_3 | misc_1 | misc_2 
 Food    |  $500   | $1,000  | $750   | $8,000 | $5,700
```

As much as possible, I don't like to put every single items in the "item IN ([1],...)"

Please let me know if it's possible to combine those group items into single column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same query but dynamically, something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colnames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(item)
                       FROM tbl_product AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 
                        QUOTENAME(item) + 'AS' +   
                        CASE WHEN rn < 7 THEN QUOTENAME('Item_' + CAST(item AS NVARCHAR(5)))
                        ELSE QUOTENAME('Misc_' + CAST(item AS NVARCHAR(5))) END
                     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY item) AS rn, item FROM tbl_product) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT category, '+ @colnames + '

FROM (
SELECT category, item, SUM(total) as item_total 
FROM (
     SELECT category, item, total
     FROM tbl_product
     ) prod
GROUP BY category, item) sourcetable
PIVOT
(
AVG(item_total)
FOR item IN (' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p';

execute(@query);
```

**Note that:**

For the column names, I used:

```
SELECT @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 
                        QUOTENAME(item) + 'AS' +   
                        CASE WHEN rn < 7 THEN QUOTENAME('Item_' + CAST(item AS NVARCHAR(5)))
                        ELSE QUOTENAME('Misc_' + CAST(item AS NVARCHAR(5))) END
                     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY item) AS rn, item FROM tbl_product) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

To select those the first 7 items with the names `item_`, whereas the rest of the items with the names `Misc_`. You can edit in this statement to customize how you would like to display the items' names.